# cannot connect to beagle-bone with IP address

Tags: unix, networking, ip-address, beagleboard

trying to connect to my beagle-bone with a client-server code I built.
my code worked with no problam with other deviced and us well by using local-host debuging si im sure its okay.
the error I get :
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I took the IP from the beaglebone by 
hostname -I

same error

when i'm "putting" my server on the PC and the "client" is the beaglebone it's working. for my win7 PC , I found the address from IPCONFIG

any Idea?

Comment: Your description isn't clear/complete enough for me to help, but I would recommending using a tool like telnet or even ping to make sure that you have a valid route from the client to the server, and that you can connect on the desired port. Essentially removing your own code first, to make sure it's not a network/config issue.

Comment: thanks @jrel, offcourse I tried pinging , but I recieve a different IP .

Answer (score 0):

finding beaglebone IP and dealing with it is well described here

http://emacstragic.net/howto-quickly-find-beaglebone-blacks-ip-address/

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes, I connected BBB with my Mac with ethernet cable, and set static IP for `eth0` interface on BBB and `en0` on mac. On BBB I modified [/etc/network/interfaces](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.100.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.100.1
```

And I set 192.168.100.1 as IP for the interface on the Mac.